# Container UserControl - Handle and Modify Added Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, windows-forms-designer, designer

I'm trying to create a custom container as `UserControl`.

**My Goal:** I want to be able to drag controls inside the designer and handle incoming controls inside the code of my usercontrol.

**Example:** I place my container somewhere and then add a button. In this momemt I want my usercontrol to automatically adjust the width and position of this button. Thats the point where Im stuck.

**My code:**

```
[Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner, System.Design", typeof(IDesigner))]
public partial class ContactList : UserControl
{
    public ContactList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }        

    private void ContactList_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Control.Width = 200;   // Nothing happens
        e.Control.Height = 100;  // Nothing happens

        MessageBox.Show("Test"); // Firing when adding a control
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

The `MessageBox` is working well. The set `width` and `height` is ignored.
The question is just "why?".

---

**EDIT**

I've just noticed, when placing the button and recompiling with F6 the button gets resized to 200x100. Why isnt this working when placing?

I mean... the `FlowLayoutPanel` handles added controls right when you place it. Thats the exact behaviour im looking for.

[image]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.icomponentchangeservice%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The main problem of your code is it doesn't apply the size. To make it apply the size, you should set the size using `BeginInvoke`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using OnControlAdded**

To fix your code, when you drop a control on container and you want to set some properties in [`OnControlAdded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.oncontroladded(v=vs.110).aspx) you should set properties using [`BeginInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx), this way the size of control will change but the size  handles don't update. Then to update the designer, you should notify the designer about changing size  of the control, using [`IComponentChangeService.OnComponentChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.icomponentchangeservice.oncomponentchanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Following code executes only when you add a control to the container. After that, it respects to the size which you set for the control using size grab handles. It's suitable for initialization at design-time.

```
protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnControlAdded(e);
    if (this.IsHandleCreated)
    {
        base.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            e.Control.Size = new Size(100, 100);
            var svc = this.GetService(typeof(IComponentChangeService)) 
                          as IComponentChangeService;
            if (svc != null)
                svc.OnComponentChanged(e.Control, 
                   TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(e.Control)["Size"], null, null);
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: I've taken the example from msdn which @HansPassant posted in the first comment. This anwser cames close to it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.icomponentchangeservice%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: If you don't use `BeginInvoke`, it would not work for `Width` and `Height` but for properties like `Dock` it will work without `BeginInvoke` and it's probably because when we set the size without `BeginInvoke` it's before the designer sets the default size provided by control and then it will replace our provided value, but using `BeginInvoke` it uses our provided value, after finishing the task of adding control to the parent.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. Ill check that in some minutes and post back.

Comment: `OnComponentChanged` isnt triggering for me. `OnComponentAdded` is working well. Unfortunately I need a combination of both. Do you have an idea why the `Changed` event isnt firing? I resized some controls in the designer and nothing happend...

Comment: I'll remove solution 2 since I think it needs some enhancements. Hope you find the answer useful :)

Comment: Then some info for you: `OnComponentChanged` passes `ComponentChangedEventArgs e`. There is no `e.Control`. You rather have to `var control = e.Component as Control;`. :)

Comment: Yes, thank you, I used it too, if you need the previous edit you can simply see it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36484098/revisions).

Comment: The problem with solution is, it changes all controls after adding them even to the form and not to our container. And it's the reason that I removed it, it needs some enhancements. Now if you are using solution 2 you should have the same issue, but solution 1 is working as expected.

Comment: Not that hard to handle I guess. Something like `if((e.Component as Control).Parent == this` => handle controls.

Comment: No it doesn't fix the problem. I checked it. Currently I prefer to use the first solution. I think it's more reliable and useful:)

Comment: The control has not parent yet, so `Control.Parent` is null and it seems t he `OnControlAdded` solution is better. Let me know the solution which you used at last. I only used `OnComponentChanged` to notify the designer about changing the component.

Comment: `FlowLayoutPanel` doesn't perform the same thing, it performs layout using `LayoutEngine`. Also it has a custom designer which handles dragged items.

Comment: *Let me know the solution which you used at last.* I remember you were not satisfied with the solution so you didn't vote for the post. Could you find a better solution? :)

Comment: In the end I switched to the currently posted solution. It was working in general. The whish for this kind of design according the recommended behaviour of controls was just overkill. I reordered my thoughts and left this for another design. I was trying hard to build an own layout-panel. But then... I just picked a tabcontrol. Anyway, your (now) posted solution worked for the parts we were discussing.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback :)